# Window peek view on Windows 10 (not desktop)

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

Is there a feature or software that allows the user to view an open window (a browser for example) when they hover the mouse on a corner/edge of the screen or on a floating button ?
The feature I am looking for is similar to the desktop peek view on windows that shows the desktop when the user hovers the mouse on the bottom right corner of the screen. But instead of showing the windows, I want a window to be shown

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application open, and the icon is on the taskbar, you can hover over the icon and then hover over the window to see the "peek view" you're looking for.